# what does this regex expression mean - ^/Home/Ignore$|^/Ignore\.aspx$|^/Content/?

Tags: regex

I have:

```
<add key="IgnorePathRegex" value="^/Home/Ignore$|^/Ignore\.aspx$|^/Content/" />
```

I need to change the value to `/Uploads/Logos`. At present I think it is `/Home/Ignore/Content/`, but not totally sure.

Comment: the pipeline symbol means OR.  at the moment you have three completely different sections.  you could add more if you like.

Comment: Check [this reference out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It currently matches the following:

```
/Home/Ignore
/Ignore.aspx
/Content/* (anything under /Context/ including /Context)
```

Comment: Thanks. I just tried with some online testers, and they complained about "/" being unescaped, and therefore my Regex expression is not valid. Is this correct?

Comment: Depends on the library you are (or online tools are) using. Your regex could be valid..

Answer (score 2):

**Explanation of the regex:**

```
^/Home/Ignore$   # Match if the entire string is /Home/Ignore
|                # or
^/Ignore\.aspx$  # Match if the entire string is /Ignore.aspx
|                # or
^/Content/       # Match if the string starts with /Content/
```

`^` and `$` are [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html); if you want to add another option, just append it with `|`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the `/Uploads/Logos` into the list:

```
 value="^/Home/Ignore$|^/Ignore\.aspx$|^/Content/|^/Uploads/Logos$"
```

Or, if you want only the `/Uploads/Logos`:

```
 value="^/Uploads/Logos$"
```

Answer to the question that is on title: Your regex has several paths checking which are or'd with pipe(`|`)